# Commit hook in Phabricator has not PHABRICATOR_ENV and tries to login in mysql as root without a password

Tags: php, mysql, git, repository, phabricator

I have installed Phabricator (http://phabricator.org/) and resolve all issues, but when i try to push into my git repo (through the file protocol, like /home/user/www/phabricator/repo/TEST) - Phabricator's commit hook throws the exception with message:

```
remote: [2014-02-24 12:08:17] EXCEPTION: (AphrontQueryConnectionException) Attempt to connect to root@localhost failed with error #1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). at [/home/user/www/phabricator/libphutil/src/aphront/storage/connection/mysql/AphrontMySQLiDatabaseConnection.php:62]
```

I use root:123123@localhost in my config and web application runs well.

There is no PHABRICATOR_ENV in getSelectedEnvironmentName method (class PhabricatorEnv) and it doesn't use needed config file.

How can i run commit hook without web access to repository?

UPD. even if i write needed env in commit_hook.php - i have another similar exception with the message

```
remote: [2014-02-24 15:32:00] EXCEPTION: (Exception) usage: PHABRICATOR_USER should be defined! at [/home/user/www/phabricator/phabricator/scripts/repository/commit_hook.php:36]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this alternate version of the question:

https://secure.phabricator.com/T4471